# understanding how to construct a higher order markov chain

Tags: algorithm, markov-chains

Suppose I want to predict if a person is of `class1=healthy` or of `class2= fever`. I have a data set with the following domain: `{normal,cold,dizzy}`

The transition matrix would contain the probability of transition generated from our training dataset while the initial vector would contain the probability that a person starts(day1) with a state x from the domain `{normal,cold,dizzy}`, again this is also generated from our training set.

If I want to build a first order markov chain, I would generate a 3x3 transition matrix and a 1x3 initial vector per class like so:

```
> TransitionMatrix
       normal cold dizzy
normal     NA   NA    NA
cold       NA   NA    NA
dizzy      NA   NA    NA

>Initial Vector
     normal cold dizzy
[1,]     NA   NA    NA
```

The NA will be filled with the corresponding probabilities.

1-My question is about transition matrices in higher order chain. For example in second order MC would we have a transition matrix of size `domain²xdomain²` like so:

```
               normal->normal normal->cold normal->dizzy cold->normal cold->cold cold->dizzy dizzy->normal dizzy->cold dizzy->dizzy
normal->normal             NA           NA            NA           NA         NA          NA            NA          NA           NA
normal->cold               NA           NA            NA           NA         NA          NA            NA          NA           NA
normal->dizzy              NA           NA            NA           NA         NA          NA            NA          NA           NA
cold->normal               NA           NA            NA           NA         NA          NA            NA          NA           NA
cold->cold                 NA           NA            NA           NA         NA          NA            NA          NA           NA
cold->dizzy                NA           NA            NA           NA         NA          NA            NA          NA           NA
dizzy->normal              NA           NA            NA           NA         NA          NA            NA          NA           NA
dizzy->cold                NA           NA            NA           NA         NA          NA            NA          NA           NA
dizzy->dizzy               NA           NA            NA           NA         NA          NA            NA          NA           NA
```

here the cell `(1,1)` represents the following sequence: `normal->normal->normal->normal`

or would it instead be just `domain²xdomain` like so:

```
               normal cold dizzy
normal->normal     NA   NA    NA
normal->cold       NA   NA    NA
normal->dizzy      NA   NA    NA
cold->normal       NA   NA    NA
cold->cold         NA   NA    NA
cold->dizzy        NA   NA    NA
dizzy->normal      NA   NA    NA
dizzy->cold        NA   NA    NA
dizzy->dizzy       NA   NA    NA
```

here the cell `(1,1)` represents `normal->normal->normal` which is different from the previous representation

2-What about the initial vector for a MC of degree 2. Would we need two initial vectors of size `1xdomain` like so:

```
     normal cold dizzy
[1,]     NA   NA    NA
```

leading to two initial vectors per class. the first giving the probability of occurrence of `{normal,cold,dizzy}` on the first day for the `healthy/fever` class while the second gives the probability of occurrence on the second day for the `healthy/fever`. this would give 4 initial vectors.

OR would we just need one initial vector of size `1xdomain²`like so:

```
    normal->normal normal->cold normal->dizzy cold->normal cold->cold cold->dizzy dizzy->normal dizzy->cold dizzy->dizzy
[1,]             NA           NA            NA           NA         NA          NA            NA          NA           NA
```

I can see how the second way of representing the initial vector would be problematic in case we want to classify an observation with only one state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say the set of spaces is *S*. Typically, in the *n*th order,

1. The transition matrix has dimensions *|S|<sup>n</sup> X |S|*. This is because given the current *n* history of states, we need the probability of the single next state. It is true that this single next state induces another compound state of history *n*, but the transition itself is to the single next state. See [this example in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Music), e.g..
2. The initial distribution is a distribution over *|S|<sup>n</sup>* elements (your second option).

Comment: For the second one suppose I have an observation with only one state say `normal`. How would I retrieve that from the the initial distribution ? Should I sum over all of these   `normal->normal normal->cold normal->dizzy` (Not sure if I made this question clear enough)

Comment: @Imlerith If IIUC your question, it is how to calculate the marginal distribution from the joint distribution. This is [well known](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/54472/given-a-table-defining-the-joint-probabilities-how-do-i-calculate-certain-param).

Comment: I am currently learning higher order markov chains, do you have any good litterature to reccomend? I have trouble finding it. I mostly find powerpoints online but without any references.
Im intrested on how the transition matrix will be for a absorbing higher order markov chain. Meaning that one or more states are impossible to leave once the chain is in it.
 Thanks :)